# How can I set up the VS Code correctly? Maybe the terminal is not designed for this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle

Why does the same piece of code work differently in different programs? See the code I provided.

```
ultimate_answer = 21+21
```

Why does the code work fine in the IDLE, while an error appears in the Visual Studio Code program. Do you have any recommendations for use. I have already looked at many articles, but I did not find a solution for my case

Here is what I see in the terminal:

```
ultimate_answer : The term 'ultimate_answer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ultimate_answer = 21+21
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ultimate_answer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I already chose PowerShell and Command Prompt - it doesn't work.

Comment: Because you're trying to run Python code outside of a Python environment. Try running `python3` to start a Python REPL, _then_ `ultimate_answer = 21+21`.

Comment: You don't appear to be running Visual Studio at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ python3
```

When start the python prompt:

```
>>> ultimate_answer = 21+21
>>> print(f"The ultimate answer is:{ultimate_answer}")
```

result:

```
The ultimate answer is:42
```